# I have multiple section and each section it has multiple rows. i want to load more cells while scroll

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have multiple section and each section n number of rows. i want to load more cells before end of scroll  collection view . i have tried with the following in cellforrowatindexpath but it get stucks and unusual behaviour.

```
  if indexPath.row ==  transactionsGroupedByDate[indexPath.section].1.count - 5        {
    self.loadMore()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you have a `.1.` here :

```
transactionsGroupedByDate[indexPath.section].1.count
```

If you model is ok with this, and `loadMore` is called (add a breakpoint to check it)

Be sure the method `loadMore` load datas in background thread. If the UI is stuck, it means you have a request or long work on the main thread.